# Cannot access id in the template objects in the props.items array

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a real estate portfolio. Each item renders as a Card and there I have a button to redirect to **UpdateRealEstate** component  and path `http://localhost:3000/pages/:pageId/:templateId` where I have a form to fill fields again.

I render all templates under path to `http://localhost:3000/pages/:pageId`. I want to access **tempalateId** when I click the edit button so I can use endpoint to make a patch request using **templateId** as well.

I'm trying to receive templateId from props that is passing, but every time I log templateId it returns undefined. It looks like does not receive any ID at all. Both `{props.id}` and `{template.id}` returns undefined.

I can access other fields to display such as **price**, and **location**.

In my parent component which is **TemplateRealEstate**. I'm rendering templates that comes from backend. Later, I render them in `<FormList items={loadedTemplates} />`.

In my **FormList** component, I'm rendering each items such as;

```
return (
      <ul className="form-list">
        {props.items.map((template) => (
          <FormItem
            key={template.id}
            id={template.id}
            price={template.price}
            // other fields
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
  );
```

In my **FormItem** component I'm receiving props and display in the page;

```
return (
    <li className="real-estate-item">
      <Card className="real-estate-item__content" >
        <div className="real-estate-item__image">{images}</div>

        <div className="real-estate-item__info">
        <h1>{props.id}</h1>
          <h1>{props.price} €</h1>
          <h3>
            {props.category}, {props.adStatus}, {props.numberOfRooms}+1,{" "}
            {props.metreSquare}m²
          </h3>
          <h4>{props.location}</h4>
         
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleTemplateClick}>Edit</button>
      </Card>
    </li>
  );
```

I was also having error of

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `FormList`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at FormItem (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2619:77)
    at FormList (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2769:77)
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at TemplateRealEstate (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3393:96)
    at div
    at UpdatePage (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1548:88)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51363:5)
    at Outlet (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51700:26)
    at ProtectedRoutes
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51363:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51785:5)
    at main
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51723:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50081:5)
    at App
```

since the beginning but since I was displaying props I ignored it. I'm not sure if that's why I cannot receive id props. I really don't get it and don't know where am I doing wrong...

Comment: It would be best to put your solution as an answer to this question and mark it as the correct one.

Comment: I gotta wait 2 days to accept my answer, but thanks! ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not receiving ID from backend correctly. Since I was using MongoDB I should have used **getters:true** to make it ID as literally ID, I believe otherwise it becomes **_id**.

```
const getTemplatesByPageId = (req, res, next) => {
    const pageId = req.params.pageId;
  
    TemplateRE.find({ pageId: pageId })
      .then((templates) => {
        const transformedTemplates = templates.map((template) => template.toObject({ getters: true }));
  
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "Templates retrieved successfully",
          templates: transformedTemplates,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res.status(500).json({
          error: error,
        });
      });
  };
```